# Create function which checks if I pressed inside of element of Graphics2D and link this with ActionListener

Tags: java, actionlistener, graphics2d

I would like ask what is the best way of creating such a function in java? I have my JPanel and this picture below as ImageIcon with Rectangle2D objects (black frames).

[image: buttons with Rectangle2D]

Now I just want to simply check if I pressed inside of one of frames and use this information in ActionListener function, like:

```
public void ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object obj = e.getSource();
    if(obj == DownloadButton) {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

So, is there a better and maybe faster way of doing such a thing? Or I have to make function like this below:

```
public void checkCoordinaes(int x, int y) {
    if(button1.contains(x, y)) { 
        isDownloadButtonClicked = true; 
    }
}
```

and link this with the ActionListener(how?)?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use a combined image rather than separate it out into one image per button? Then you could make JButtons with the appropriate icons and it would be easy, and toss them in a GridLayout or somesuch.

Comment: My combined image has 22 buttons and kind of "touchscreen". Is it a good reason? ;)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by touchscreen. But in my opinion, you're better off putting in the time to break up the image and using Swing the way it's streamlined to be used rather than trying to take a shortcut that requires a convoluted workaround. You'll save time in the long run and the people who come after you will thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to implement it as a single JPanel with an image, you should create a MouseListener to listen for MouseEvents.  These will give you the x-y coordinates of the mouse click, which you can pass to your checkCoordinates() function:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
{
    checkCoordinates(e.getX(), e.getY());
}
```

Comment: I know how to use my checkCoordinates function with mouse listener, but thank you anyway :)

Comment: Was responding to the "link it to ActionListener(how?)" - you can't if you're not using components that raise ActionEvents (like JButtons).  Was trying to give you a thorough response to an alternative approach, apologies if it was below your level. :)